# substitue @signs not followed by \n

Tags: linux, sed, terminal

I have a file that looks like

```
dwfsdv  @
sdvs dfbvdfb gfb dgf@
substitute this @rfg dfg dsgdf g@
asdfsfsfdsfds this @rsdf@
WDSFSD FS@
```

and I am trying to substitute the @ in the middle of the text that does not include the ones followed by \n by using sed such that the output looks like

```
dwfsdv  @
sdvs dfbvdfb gfb dgf@
substitute this [(ATsignnowAT)]rfg dfg dsgdf g@
asdfsfsfdsfds this [(ATsignnowAT)]rsdf@
WDSFSD FS@
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to match an @ followed by a character. Capture that character and include it in the substitution

```
sed -E 's/@(.)/[(ATsignnowAT)]\1/g'
```

An @ at the end-of-line will not be followed by a character and thus will not match.